# How can I download file using Angular 5?

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular5

When I paste `my_example_link` in a browser the file is automatically downloaded in a proper way. However, when I use source code shown below download doesn't work. I would like to download file after clicking `download` button. Any ideas what is wrong? I don't get any errors.

user.service.ts:

```js
DownloadFiles() {

    return this.http.get('my_example_link', {responseType: 'text'});

}
```

uploader.service.ts:

```js
DownloadFile(){

      this.userService.DownloadFiles()
          .subscribe(
              (data) => this.downloadFile2(data)), // console.log(data),
              (error) => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
              () => console.info("OK");
}

downloadFile2(data: Response){
  var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
  var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
}
```

something.component.html:

```html
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="isCloud()">
    <a  (click)="this.UploaderService.DownloadFile()" download="file23.txt" style='cursor: pointer;' class="nav-link" target="_blank">
        <i class="nc-icon nc-basket"></i> Download
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: the easiest way to get a file to download is to use the download attribute provided natively by most modern browsers shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp  ... if you absolutely must do it via xhr, then the easiest way is to set the correct response headers on the server. Otherwise you'll run into some head aches.

Comment: @bryan60 the problem is that I download this file from hadoop through backend using `HttpResponseRedirect`, so I need to send data for instance in blob and then save it in local system of the user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **arraybuffer**

```
this.httpClient.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer',headers:headers});
```

To save File:

```
 npm install file-saver --save

 import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';
```

component:

```
downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type.toString() });
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        saveAs(blob,"file_name.txt");
        window.open(url);

    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to save file which was converted to blob with his original name? At the moment I save file with name `unknown`.

Comment: Forgive me if I didn't define it clearly enough. I meant whether it is possible to download file using blob with his filename? In the example above we add the name of the file manually. I wonder whether it is possible to do this automatically using blob. Or blob only contains information about file without his name?

Comment: i meant to say if you are getting response as file with original name you can save

Comment: you need to create an object which consist filedata, filename, filetype etc. send that object from api.

Comment: It works properly. I wonder now if there is any similar way to display only the file without downloading it?

Comment: In case someone get error "cannot find module 'file-saver/FileSaver'", FileSaver was lying in the dist folder in file-saver. So the path will be "import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/dist/FileSaver'"